# What safe ways are there to get a baby to sneeze?

Tags: infant, health

Our daughter has a cold, and is struggling to clear her nose. We have tried (deep breath) Olbas Oil, a Nasal Aspirator, Sea water Nasal Spray, and Vapour rub, but nothing is as effective as when she sneezes. Other than tickling her under her nose are there any other tricks for getting her to sneeze on demand?

Comment: I don't know how to get anyone to sneeze :), but I have you tried salt water drops? that helps loosen things up. A warm bath also helps, especially after the drops.

Comment: Hot showers while she's in the room are pretty helpful for this (both sneezing and loosening stuff).  Also, bright lights in the eyes supposedly cause this.

Comment: I accidentally nicked the tip of my nose last week while shaving (I was still waking up, okay?), and used a styptic pencil to stop the bleeding, which stings like crazy.  Made me sneeze around 6 times, big sneezes too.  Oh wait, you said "safe." :-)

Comment: Apart from @Karl ;-), thanks for the tips.

Comment: @theBunk "apart from@Karl ;-), thanks for the tips." No pun intended right?

Answer (score 2):

Expose your child to bright light (like a clouded sky). Not too long, of course. A large percentage of people will sneeze when exposed to bright light. See [photic sneezing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photic_sneeze_reflex#Photic_sneezing).